# Make Mithril application SEO friendly

Tags: javascript, mithril.js

Me and my friend have created a website which we want to use as en experiment for school purpose.

https://www.daniellindgren.se/

But we are encountering some problem when we want Google bots to crawl the subpages, like CV and contact.
When we use Google webmaster tool to how the indexing from Google goes, it says that they can't crawl anything else then the startpage.
We have built a sitemap and we have also declared that in the robots.txt.
But we read somewhere that Mithril can cause problem for Google bots because their links to subpages starts with an "?". 
Is there any workaround for that we can use or what other solution is there? Should we maybe try to re-make it a single-page application instead?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any "?" in the links on your site, and in general Google should be able to index SPA:s nowadays.

But it's not always working, so an option could be to use Mithril to render the templates server-side as well. Depending on your backend it may take a little bit of work. If you're using Node.js it's easy with [mithril-node-render](https://github.com/StephanHoyer/mithril-node-render), if not I recommend [Haxe](https://haxe.org) and [mithril-hx](https://github.com/ciscoheat/mithril-hx) for cross-platform support.

Then you need to change the [routing strategy](https://mithril.js.org/route.html#routing-strategies) so a request from outside the application hits the server as well. Unless you think about it from the beginning, you probably need to rewrite quite a bit of the backend to make it more isomorphic.

But your site doesn't have much client-side functionality however, so as it is right now, I'd treat the site as a non-SPA, and use Mithril when you want some dynamic, ajax-driven functionality.